# HTC Desire HD Wifi proxy applicaiton

Tags: htc-desire, htc-desire-hd, proxy

Is there any working application (root does not matter) for using proxy on HTC Desire HD. ProxyDroid is not working on HTC Desire HD. SSH Tunnel is also not working on it.

Comment: Note that *Can you suggest an app that does X?* questions are off-topic (see [FAQ]). But a simple answer is to search the playstore for "proxy". You might want to take a look at [ASProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Alsu.ASProxy) and [SandroProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy) for a start.